# Javascript replace function clarification

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn javascript
i have this code:

```
x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
```

can i have a description about    /^\s+|\s+$/g,""

searching to replace what with what ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html). Basically `\s` matches whitespac characters and replaces them with `""`.

edit:
`/ ... /` marks the regex.

`^\s+` Take 1or more whitespaces at the beginning of the string.

`\s+$` Take 1 or more whitespaces at the end of the string.

`/g` Dont stop at the first match, but find all matches - "global flag"

Answer (score 0):

It's removing whitespaces, either at the beginning or the end of the string, by replacing them with the empty string `""`.

You can find more about regular expressions here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp.

Answer (score 0):

first, look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp and then do not use stackoverflow for questions of this kind

Comment: First don't use w3schools links and then do not use Stackoverflow for answers of this kind.

Comment: easy easy  guys , its maybe a silly question for most of u , but im learning here , thanks for all ur effort , regards